# Service Fabric mount network drive on nodes

Tags: azure, powershell, batch-file, azure-service-fabric, azure-files

I've tried to mount a network drive during service startup.
I followed these tutorials, but cannot figure out the proper solution.

Created a fileshare: [Quickstart: Create and manage Azure Files share with Windows virtual machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-quick-create-use-windows)

Added the `SetupEntryPoint` to `ServiceManifest` [Run script at service startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-run-script-at-service-startup)

I added logging, to find the errors too (`ConsoleRedirection` part):

```
  <SetupEntryPoint>
      <ExeHost>
        <Program>InitNetworkDrives.bat</Program>
        <WorkingFolder>CodePackage</WorkingFolder>
        <ConsoleRedirection FileRetentionCount="10"/>
      </ExeHost>
    </SetupEntryPoint>
```

The InitNetworkDrives.bat is working properly

```
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command %cd%\MountNetworkDrive.ps1
```

it calls a `PowerShell` script, which is responsible for mounting the new network drive:

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PASSSSWOOOOOOOOOOOORD" -AsPlainText -Force
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Azure\fileshare", $password)
New-PSDrive -Name W -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\fileshare\something-Credential $Cred -Persist -Scope Global
```

In case I call the .bat or .ps1 script locally, the drive mounts properly. However during `ServiceFabric` deploy, there are issues with user rights, and no way I can create the mounted drive. I'm quite sure the issue is caused by the user rights. By default the `ServiceFabric` uses the `NetworkService` user, but I tried to do it with `LocalSystem`, `LocalService`, `LocalUser`...
[Run a service as a local user account or local system account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security)
I start to think the best way would be to use a Git repo on the VM instead of a mounted network drive.

### UPDATE

I've tried @Compo's fixes, but the drive is not there anyway.
I also added a drive check prior to the New-PSDrive call, and have a bit more detailed log.

```
$Networkpath = "B:" 
$pathExists = Test-Path -Path $Networkpath
echo "Mount started"
If (-not ($pathExists)) {
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PAWWWWSRORD" -AsPlainText -Force
echo "password : $password"
$Cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("Azure\fileshare", $password)
echo "Cred : $Cred"
New-PSDrive -Name B -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\fileshare\algorithmconfigs -Credential $Cred -Persist -Scope Global  
echo "New-PSDrive done"
}
else {
echo "Path already existed"
Return      #end the function if path was already there
}
```

The script runs without any issues, and the log tells me everything went fine, but the drive is not there in the explorer.

```
Mount started
password : System.Security.SecureString
Cred : System.Management.Automation.PSCredential

Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                               CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                               ---------------
B                   0.00          1.00 FileSystem    \\stalgorithmconfigs.file.core.w...                               
New-PSDrive done
```

Comment: Unrelated to your specific issue, but you're not running a [tag:powershell] command, you're running a [tag:powershell] script. For that reason, you should change `-Command` to `-File`. Additionally, do not use `Bypass` for your Execution Policy, use `RemoteSigned`, _or if absolutely necessary, `Unrestricted`_, instead. You may have an issue with your [tag:batch-file] using `%cd%` though.

Comment: You have not provided any code or supporting information to indicate that you have set a known current directory, so I'll assume that you're expecting it to be that of the running [tag:batch-file]. That is certainly not the case, especially as you're running the script as another user. My advice therefore is to change `%cd%\ `, (which would have been better as `.\ ` anyhow), to `%~dp0` instead. This special variable expands to the drive and path of the currently running [tag:batch-file] and always has a trailing directory separator, _(backslash)_.

Comment: Also, for safety, you should surround that `.ps1` path with quotes, as it may contain problematic characters.